# Which is better way to merge selected commits from one branch to other branch in Git

Tags: git, github, release, devops, release-management

I have Master and Develop branch, developers are commit their code on Develop branch at the time of release some commits which is in develop branch not going for release so i have skip that commits while creating release branch or merging on master branch which is a best approach to handle this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the command you're looking for is `git cherry-pick`.

From [`git-cherry-pick(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

You checkout the target HEAD, keeping your WD clean, and run `git cherry-pick <commit> <commit> ...` and Git will do the rest. In case of a conflict, just solve it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than cherry picking, a better practice is to use feature toggles to conditionally enable/disable features. This allows you to keep your code fully integrated at all times.

If you've merged a dozen commits to your `develop` branch and tested them, cherry picking a handful of commits means **all of your testing is invalidated**. You don't know if the commits you've cherry picked actually work properly.